# What could be the reason for constant variables changing value?

Tags: c++

I define a constant variable as:

```
class Client {

private:
  const int payloadLen = 8 * 1024;
```

And than later I print variable values:

```
  std::cout << "Payload len " << payloadLen << "\n";
```

Which comes out as `0`.
What are possible reasons of this happening?
This happens depending on which version of 3rd party binary I am building against. And when I get 0 it unavoidably leads to a SegFault later.

Comment: Undefined behaviour? Someone stomping your memory? If the program is crashing the explanation is often "something went wrong" but you'll have to find out what, precisely.

Comment: My best bet is cosmic radiation frying your dram at precisely the right time and location every time you run. Other than that, it could be anything really

Comment: Try running your program through valgrind.  If it's depending on the version of a third-party library, then there's a chance that library has a buffer overflow bug in the offending version.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile as payloadLen was not declared in the scope.  I.e. your example is not self-contained.  My guess is that said std::cout is in a method of the class.  An option would be that you are not printing what you think you are printing.  That said, +1 on valgrind.

Comment: try to make a [mcve]

Comment: It sounds like the third party library is to blame.

Comment: I wish I could narrow it down to a reproducable example. So far, valgrind seems to be the way to go further

Comment: "depending on which version" suggests an ODR violation - different parts of the program don't agree on the size or binary layout of some class.

Answer (score 0):

Different parts of the project were compiled with different `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` flags (one part was borrowing the flag from the 3rd party library). Symptom was identified after studying 2 compilations side by side with `VEBROSE=1` var for `cmake`. Passing strings between 2 parts of the project was scrambling the memory.